# How to select rows from character array that match char string and save them in a new array?

Tags: matlab

I have a char array A which basically contains a list of files names (each row one file)
(char, 526x26)

```
val =

0815_5275_UBA_A_1971.txt  
0815_5275_UBA_A_1972.txt  
0823_6275_UBA_A_1971.txt  
0823_6275_UBA_A_1972.txt  
0823_6275_UBA_A_1973.txt
...
```

I also have a variable

```
B = '0815_5275'
```

I'd like to select all rows (filenames) that start with B and save them in a new array C.

This should be simple, but somehow I can't make it work.
I've got this:

```
C = A(A(:,1:9) == B);
```

but I get the error message:

```
Error using  == 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

I do not know in advance how many rows will match, so I can not pre-define an empty array.

thanks, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ismember(A(:, 1:numel(B)), B, 'rows')` rather to get a logical vector that indexes only the rows you want

and now

`A(C,:)` to extract the rows

The reason you're getting a dimension mismatch error is because your A(:,1:9) has many rows but B only has one and Matlab does not automatically broadcast like Octave or Python. You could do it using either `repmat` or `bsxfun` but in this case `ismember` is the correct function to choose.

Comment: @EitanT Yes my bad, I made two mistakes which coicidentally cancelled each other out for this particular example data. Corrected now.